# How to deploy python programs in Anaconda environments on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, deployment, anaconda

I am trying to use Anaconda and conda environments to allow Python programs for data acquisition* etc. to run from the (Anaconda) command line on Windows.  The set up will be that the Python programs are installed to a particular location (cloned from Github), within %PATH% or whichever environment variable is more appropriate.

From an Anaconda command prompt in another directory and a particular conda environment, I want (both myself and other users) to be able run either `python test.py <args>` or `test.py <args>` (either solution is acceptable) and have a system wide conda environment run its Python to execute the program.  test.py can/will have an appropriate shebang set.

Right now the `python test.py` calls the correct Python within the active conda environment, but cannot find the test.py program as Python won't search the %PATH% or similar looking for the program. `test.py` does something (Windows does not complain that the executable can't be found, and I've been playing with the file associations to get this far), but doesn't appear to start Python - a simple print function or raise statement as the only entry in the file does nothing.

I've tried setting file associations in Windows, but this hasn't changed anything.  I've copied the py.exe/pyw.exe across to the Anaconda environments, with no change.

Is this something that can be done within Anaconda, or am I going to have to fall back on installing base Python directly and trying to use the launcher mechanism there?

Note that I'm also intending to deploy these programs on Raspbian, so any solutions, including non-Anaconda ones, that will work cross platform there would be worth extra effort on my part.

*these programs have significant usage of library packages for accessing external USB/GPIB/serial/ethernet connected lab equipment and use matplotlib, scipy, etc., hence the desire for a cloneable conda environment as the base environment.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the correct answer to this is fairly simple, but is fairly hard to find explained well. This might be a little clearer than the other answers I found:

Install the standalone launcher from [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/overview) and add `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebangs to your scripts.

This should register .py files to Python.File and will find your Anaconda Pythons in appropriate environments.  If you don't have a non-Anaconda python, it will use the Anaconda base environment (these two facts were the key element I was missing from various other answers around this problem that I had looked at, including the documents on `python.org`).

If you have a Python from `python.org` installed, then a standalone command line shell will use that, defaulting to Python 2.x, then Python 3.x.  With `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang, then a regular command shell will try to use `python.org` pythons first, then the Anaconda base environment.  An Anaconda prompt will use the active environment.  `#! /usr/bin/env python2` or `python3` will try to use `python.org` pythons only and fail if they are not found.

Installing Python 2.7 from `python.org` installers (and letting the installer set the file associations) will break pylauncher, and reinstalling will not fix it.  Instead, set `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open\command` default value to `"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*` to revert back to the pylauncher set up (assuming you used the `launchwin.*` packages to install it).